# UICollectionView with bouncing animation

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to load UICollectionView cells in a way that the sections in UICollectionView are loading one by one with an animation that slides from right to left. Once it slides in from right to left, I want it to bounce/shake and then second section slides in and bounce with same effect. I'm able to slide in the sections but once it enters from right to left I can't make it bounce/shake a little. Below is my code that I'm trying:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
            attributes.transform3D = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(self.collectionView.bounds.size.width, 0, 0);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished){
            attributes.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -120);
            //code needed to make it bounce a little
        }];
```

Comment: Do you did it? @mughees-musaddiq